How to setup a daily backup restore procedure for Elasticsearch
How to setup a daily backup restore procedure for Elasticsearch.
We backup from Elastic cloud instance to local docker ES instance for testing purpose.
We would like to setup an incremental backup of ES and not download and re-import the data every day and we want all the modified entries to be overwritten on the target instance.
How to achieve this with https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump, right now we dump data, mappings once

Yo! You can try following the ES snapshot and restore procedures, snapshots deduplicate data based on index segments: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html
